# How to add Table with header cells in the top row and first column using Buefy table

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I would like to make a table using buefy that looks like this one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the table design component cannot be seen on the buefys docs website. There are `three` things that you can do.

First, you can override the css style of the buefy table component, Second, you can add a body and a header inside the buefy table components default slot, or you can just create it your own.

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <td></td>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thrusday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>9:00 - 11:00</th>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>11:00 - 13:00</th>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>13:00 - 15:00</th>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>15:00 - 17:00</th>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Closed</td>
      <td>Open</td>
      <td>Open</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will just make my own.